# Write to Firebase Storage and Firestore in an atomic transaction

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740838/couple-firebase-firestore-and-firebase-storage-calls-together-into-a-batch) 5y old question asking whether it is possible to write to both Firebase Storage and Firestore in an atomic way: either both succeed or both fail.

I am asking again, as the core product has evolved a lot.

My use case is I want to upload a file to Storage, get the URL and upload it to Firestore.

Comment: Nope, there is still not cross-service transaction mechanism for writing to Cloud Storage and Firestore.