# Sending text-based data in my Firebase RTDB and uploading image file in my Firebase Storage, what if one fails?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a feature in my testing application that allows users to submit text-based data and one image file per said "data collection". I have the following code to store both data:

```
let rtdbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('someNode').push();
let pushedKey = rtdbRef.key;

rtdbRef.set({
  someKey: someValue
})
.catch((e) => {
  //Handle error;
});

let storageRef = firebase.database().ref().child('images/' + pushedKey);
storage.put(myFile).then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('File upload successful');
}).catch((e) => {
  //Handle error;
});
```

As you can see, I'm uploading the data with two separate `Promise` chains. So, I changed it to the following:

```
let rtdbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('someNode').push();
let pushedKey = rtdbRef.key;
let storageRef = firebase.database().ref().child('images/' + pushedKey);

rtdbRef.set({
  someKey: someValue
})
.then({
    return storageRef.put(myFile).then((snapshot) => snapshot);
})
.catch((e) => {
  //Handle error;
});
```

I changed my initial code because I thought that **there might be a chance where my text-based data gets stored and yet my image file upload fails**. However, it seems like changing my initial code to the second one does not make anything better:

- If I separate the two chains, doesn't that mean that I'm sending **both** my text-based data and image file **simultaneously**, which makes it faster? If the answer is yes, should I stick to my initial code?
- My initial concern persists: what if the text-based data gets sent **successfully** and yet the image file upload **fails**. How do I make it so that if any of my two attempts to store data fails, I cancel the whole data storing operation?

Comment: You're calling two separate backend services, and there is no support for a transaction running across these services. You will have to deal with potential partial data by: 1) making your code robust, and 2) running periodic cleanup scripts. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319764/firebase-handle-sudden-loss-in-connection/47322207#47322207

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I see. So basically, like the code in the link you provided, is it better to wait for the file upload to finish before pushing my text-based data (I'm assuming here that text-based data is less prone to failures)? Also, how do I run *regular batch processes to cleanup data*?

Comment: There is no definitive 'better' here. You just have to make sure that your code that reads the data can handle all of the cases. I typically run cleanup code on Cloud Functions, or with a local Node.js script that I run when I have a moment.